# Java - How to make a variable that can be used anywhere?

Tags: java, variables, loops

I want to make a variable that I can use inside my method to change that variable outside my method. As a visual: (I imported the scanner class by the way)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int quitVar = 1;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    class IWantToQuit {
        public void quit() {
            quitVar++; //This is the problem area.
        }
    }
    IWantToQuit quiter = new IWantToQuit();
    while (quitVar == 1) {
        System.out.println("HELLO");
    System.out.println("Type QUIT to quit.");
    choice = scan.next();
    if (choice.equals("QUIT")) {
        quiter.quit();
    }
```

For some reason, it says that the local variable quitVar is accessed by the inner class but it needs to be declared and I have declared it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Nambari yeah i proove i didn't know xD

Answer (score 3):

This [local inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) because defined inside method. Rules for local inner class are:

> A local class has access to the members of its enclosing class.
>
> In addition, a local class has access to local variables. However, a
>   local class can only access local variables that are declared final.

In this case `quitVar` is local variable, so you need to declare it as `final` to access it inside local class. But if you declare it `final`, you can't increment.

If you want this variable accessible, then define as [class variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#local-classes-are-non-static) rather than local variable.

Comment: If I can't increment it, can I still assign it an new value with "="?

Comment: @Jacob: If you declare it as final, you can't even assign something else using =.

Comment: Ok. How would on go about defining a variable as an instance variable rather than local?

Comment: +1, but ` In the previous example, the PhoneNumber constructor accesses the member LocalClassExample.regularExpression` has no sense in your answer is out of context hihi

Comment: @nachokk: Fixed it. I just copied it from link in answer.

Comment: @Jacob: Instance variable also won't work, you need to define class variable. Refer the links I have added in my answers.

Answer (score 2):

Other people are offering you solutions but really what you're trying to do isn't a good idea.

Global variables are widely recognised as an anti pattern by most developers - so maybe there's something else we can do.

You're incrementing something but testing for 1 so if it gets called twice your code won't trigger.

If you change the int to a boolean, make it a member variable of the quitter with an accessor it'll work much better.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    class IWantToQuit {
        private boolean hasQuit = false;
        public void quit() {
            hasQuit = true;
        }

        boolean hasQuit() {
            return hasQuit;
        }
    }

    IWantToQuit quiter = new IWantToQuit();
    while (!quiter.hasQuit()) {
        System.out.println("HELLO");
        System.out.println("Type QUIT to quit.");
        String choice = scan.next();
        if (choice.equals("QUIT")) {
           quiter.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable `quitVar` outside the main() method and declare the variable as `static`

[Declaring Member Variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

[Variable Scope](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm)

[static variable](http://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they/)